# Let T:V→W be a linear transformation & S = {v_1, . . . , v_k} & S'= {T(v_1), . . . , T(v_k)} is lin dependent. Does it follow that S is lin dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

**Answer:**

We know:

$a_1T(v_1) + ... + a_kT(v_k) = 0$ where $a_i \not= 0$ for at least one $i \in \{1,...,k\}$ because S' is linearly dependent

T is linear so we can say:

$a_1T(v_1) + ... + a_kT(v_k) = T(0)$

$\Rightarrow$ $T(a_1v_1) + ... + T(a_kv_k) = T(0)$

We can take away T

$\Rightarrow$ $a_1v_1 + ... + a_kv_k = 0$ where $a_i \not= 0$ for at least one $i \in \{1,...,k\}$

$\Rightarrow$ $S = \{1,...,k\}$  is linearly dependent

I'm not to confident on the fact the I went from $0$ to $T(0)$. Is that ok and is this a suitable answer to the question.

**Edit: New and improved answer:**

**Proof By Counterexample:**

Let $T:W \rightarrow V$ $=$ $T:R^3 \rightarrow R^2$

Let $S = \{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)\}$

Let $S' = \{T(1, 0, 0), T(0, 1, 0), T(0, 0, 1)\}$

Show S' is lin dependent:

$a_1T(1, 0, 0) + a_2T(0, 1, 0) + a_3T(0, 0, 1) = 0$

$a_1(1, 1) + a_2(1, 1) + a_3(1, 1) = 0$

Let $a_1 = 1, a_2 = -1, a_3 = 0$

$(1)(1, 1) + (-1)(1, 1) + (0)(1, 1) = 0$

$(1, 1) + (-1, -1) + 0 = 0$

$(1-1, 1-1) = 0$ $\Rightarrow$ S' is lin dependent as $\exists a_i \neq 0, i \in \{1, ..., k\}$ s.t $a_1T(v_1)+ ... + a_kT(v_k)= 0$

Show S is not lin dependent:

$a_1(1, 0, 0) + a_2(0, 1, 0) + a_3(0, 0, 1) = 0$

we cannot get any non-zero value for $a_1, a_2, a_3$ to make $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3 = 0$ $\therefore$ S is linearly independent.

$\Rightarrow 0(1, 0, 0) + 0(0, 1, 0) + 0(0, 0, 1) = 0$

$\Rightarrow$ We've shown an example where S' is dependent despite S being linearly independent, proving that the statement is false.

Comment: Why can we take away $T$? Have you looked at any simple examples? Consider orthogonal projection of the $xy$-plane onto the $x$-axis, say.

Comment: The step going from $0$ to $T(0)$ is ok, because for any linear map we have $T(0)=0$. You made a mistake when "taking $T$ away" because you assumed injectivity in this step. You can easily see by the pathological example $T(x)=0$ that your statement can't be true.